# AndroidStudio sporadically stops generating ButterKnife bindings until Rebuild

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife

AndroidStudio keeps failing to generate the binding classes for classes using ButterKnife when I make changes to the views / bindings, making ButterKnife no longer work. The problem goes away when I do a full rebuild of the project... for a while, and then comes back. I haven't been able to nail down what changes trigger it.

How can I fix this? And short of fixing it, is there any way to manually get AndroidStudio to re-run AnnotationProcessors without having to do a full rebuild of the project?

**Setup details:**

- Windows 7
- Android Studio v2.2.3
- CompileSDKVersion 25
- Jack Enabled compiling using Java 8
- ButterKnife v8.5.1

Comment: I posted an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/957

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the (now finally deprecated) Jack toolchain solved this issue - as suggested by the Butterknife founders [in the issue I opened](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/957)

At the time of this writing, if you are using JAVA 8 to compile, you will have to install an AS version > 2.3.2 and update your gradle version and plugin accordingly. Then the annotations work as expected AND you get InstantRun capabilites back :)